# error to see taxonomy woocommercer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

when accessing the link of the attributes for woocommerce, it does not show me, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxOBn.png)

but if you show me the categories

I do not know if it's something from archive.php or version php, or hosting

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your site?

Comment: http://www.jdevoto.cl/web/producto/puntos-adhesivo-permanente-instant-64-unid/

Comment: when click to "Marcas" instant, I get the error

Comment: Does it work if you use a default theme like Twenty Seventeen?

Comment: It does not work for any theme, can it be something from the installation of wp?
or directives php?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do now. Attributes do not act like categories or tags. They are assigned to products and do not have archive pages. You may want to consider using tags instead of attributes for an alternative way to organize your products.

Comment: Ahhhhh ok. can be linked to archive, to taxonomy?